# Magento - automatically redirecting empty parent categories to the first child category

Tags: magento, categories, redirect

I need to redirect pages that contain no products to the first child category URL containing  products (if the child category exists)

Since I need to do this only if the category contains no products, I'm not able to do this via .htaccess

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved in Magento?
I'm not having much luck hunting through Google.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked it. You should put it in your view.phtml.

```
$currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$productCheck  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategory)
                                                   ->getProductCollection();

if (count($productCheck) < 1) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.location = "' . Mage::getUrl('somewhere') . '"
    </script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observer. You could edit/create a local catalog module and try this:

1) Define observer on your config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <!--(...)-->
    <global>
        <!--(...)-->
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_category_init_after>
                <observers>
                    <yourcompany_catalog>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourcompany_catalog/observer</class>
                        <method>categoryRedirect</method>
                    </yourcompany_catalog>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_category_init_after>
        </events>
        <!--(...)-->
    </global>
    <!--(...)-->
</config>
```

2) Your observer method can be something like this:

```
<?php
class GraspingMagento_SocialShare_Model_Observer
{

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function categoryRedirect(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
        $category = $observer->getData('category');

        if ($category->getProductCollection()->count() > 0) {
            // Category has products, no need to redirect
            return;
        }

        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection $childrenCategories */
        $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

        /** @var Mage_Catalog_CategoryController $controller */
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        foreach ($childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
            /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $childCategory */
            if ($childCategory->getProductCollection()->count() > 0) {
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($childCategory->getData('request_path'));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will verify that your current category has no products. If it doesn't, it will try to find a *direct* child that has products, and redirect to it.